# Is the Higgs bare mass larger than the physical mass?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, higgs

The Higgs boson propagator can be written $$\frac{1}{p^2-m^2+\Sigma(p^2)}$$. If we take $p^2=m_P^2$ the physical mass, we get $m_P^2=m^2-\Sigma(m_P^2)$. Now, if $\Sigma\sim \Lambda^2$, we get $m^2\sim\Lambda^2+m_P^2$.

It had assumed that the mass correction from fermion loops was positive, but from this it appears that the Higgs mass is renormalized to be smaller than the bare mass. Is this physical ?

Comment: Why would you think that the bare mass should be smaller than the physical mass?

Comment: That was first assumption because this is how it works for the electron,where self energy adds to the bare mass.

Comment: I don't have a copy on me now, or time to go look it up, but there is a nice discussion of this in section 1.1 of Aitchison's book on Supersymmetry. There is an early draft copy online [here](http://www.slac.stanford.edu/cgi-wrap/getdoc/slac-r-865.pdf) from Stanford. This link goes to the .pdf file.
Alternatively you should be able to find it in any good university library.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to answer the question and confirms that the bare mass is larger. What would be the physical interpretation of this? When we talk about the electron, it's intuitive to picture the electron field as adding to the mass. But is there a similar intuitive picture for the Higgs?

Comment: Why have you put $\Sigma\sim\Lambda^2$ and not, say, $-\Lambda^2$ ? In fact, at one loop the fermions give a negative contribution to the selfenergy whereas bosons give a positive one. In any case, you could recast your question looking just  at |m|^2 and the fact that is (much) larger of $m_P^2$ is the manifestation of hierarchy problem of the SM seen as effective field theory. For the SM in isolation with no new physics, the only physical quantity you should compared against is the running mass which, just by dimensional analysis, must be proportional to the Higgs vev.